# Get hash string / guid from a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, guid

I would like to have a hashtable of jQuery objects and needs some kind of unique identifier for them.

The DOM representation is just

```
<tr>
    ...
</tr>
```

And I would like to add my jQuery `<tr>` objects to a hashtable

`hash[$(trObject).guid()] = $(trObject);`

How can I uniquely identify a particular jQuery object without extending jQuery?

I know I could write a method

```
(function() {
    var guid = 0;
    $.fn.guid = function() {
         var node = this[0];
         if (node.guid === undefined) {
              node.guid = guid++;
         }
         return node.guid;
    };
}());
```

To do this for me, but I would prefer to know if there is some kind of native standard way to get a string/int hashcode from a jQuery object.

P.S. I don't expect to hit the 32bit integer limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No native standard way which I am aware of but there are jquery plugins for this 
eg. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/GUID_Helper

UPDATE: 
The guid number used by jquery is stored in `jquery.guid`
Moreover, jquery is not using any native standard method for this. It is also following an approach similar to yours.

Comment: I can write my own GUID wrapper. I was just wondering if I could hook into anything jQuery uses a GUID.

Comment: -1 @Shree jquery.guid is a guid handler for event handlers so it knows which to call/remove in delegate/live. It is not for DOM objects or jQuery objects.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. What I meant was that JQuery also uses an approach similar to yours